# Transpose rows to columns in mysql using query

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, transpose

I want to transfer the table :

```
platform | count
Android    100
IOS         200
```

to

```
Android | IOS
100           200
```

IN MYSQL USING QUERY

How can I do It ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up pivot tables and how they work.

> To tabulate all colID and value values against all id values—that is, to write a reporting CUBE for the table—write a GROUP_CONCAT() instruction for each colID found in the table, then GROUP BY id:

```
SELECT  
  id,  
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colID = 1, value, NULL)) AS 'First Name', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colID = 2, value, NULL)) AS 'Last Name', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colID = 3, value, NULL)) AS 'Job Title' 
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY id; 
+------+------------+-----------+----------------+ 
| id   | First Name | Last Name | Title          | 
+------+------------+-----------+----------------+ 
|    1 | Sampo      | Kallinen  | Office Manager | 
|    2 | Jakko      | Salovaara | Vice President | 
+------+------------+-----------+----------------+
```

A quick google search led me to this explanation here which answers your question and then some:
 http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78